# Taking multiple pictures with very little delay in Linux/ Raspberry pi

Tags: linux, bash, udp, raspberry-pi, webcam

I'm creating a computer vision project which requires me to capture images on a raspberry pi and send it over the network to a server to process it. The software that processes only accepts pictures and not videos but for a good user experience the faster the photos arrive the better the response time of the system. Currently, im struggling with capturing multiple images quickly and i've tried software such as fswebcam, motion , pygame.Camera and all have a delay of roughly 1 sec resulting in <=1fps. I would like to increase this to around 10 fps. In my current setup i run a bash script which takes a picture from a usb webcam and saves it on disk of the raspi and a separate piece of C code transfers the images over UDP sockets. Is there a fast way to achieve faster capture of frames and save them to disk?

Comment: How you implemented your code ? could you show an example ?

Comment: the bash script? if so its quite literally fswebcam -r 1280x720 image.jpg

Comment: Capturing multiple images quickly to transmit in real time is known as "video". Look up video streaming. Grabbing, encoding and transmitting jpgs in a bash loop is not the way to go.

Comment: I've considered capturing video but the server will only process frames. A possibility is separating the video into jpegs on the server side but im not sure if thats better.

Comment: A video is a sequence of frames. If you mean that your server software requires a .jpg on disk, that's a design problem with your server and not an inherent problem with this approach. [Here's a guide](http://zacharybears.com/low-latency-raspberry-pi-video-streaming/) for streaming live video end-to-end with 100ms delay, the rest is up to your server. Even if you don't make the server handle video streams, t'll be faster to dump the stream to jpgs on the server because it (presumably) has a beefier CPU to handle that inefficiency.

Comment: if performance is a limit, you will be faced to try both approach, both yours and those from that other guy (sounds funny :) )...